# C# Class wont allow SQL directive

Tags: c#

I have created a class to make my code more maintainable, as having it in a class with methods will reduce the size of my code by a fair bit.

However, When I try and use the SQL directive I receive an error:
"type or namespace name could not be found”

The target framework currently being used if .NET standard 2.0, I have tried to change it via the properties, however, the only versions available are 1.9 - 1.0.

My main project is using .NET framework 4.6.1 - Will having the same frameworks make a difference? Strange that I can not modify the class target framework easily...

I have done the following as well:

Right Click on Project > Manage Nuget Packages > Search & install 'System.Data.SqlClient'

I continue to receive a 'directive is unnecessary error'
(Start of code:

```
using System.Data.SqlTypes;

namespace Game
{
    public class Choice
    {
        //public SqlConnection Test;
        public sqlConnection Test;
    }
)
```

How can I connect use the `System.Data.SqlTypes` directive?

Comment: What did you want to achieve?

Comment: do you have `System.Data.dll` added to your project references?

Comment: replace `using System.Data.SqlTypes;` with `using System.Data.SqlClient;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong namespace here.

Instead of:

```
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
```

You should use [`SqlClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient?view=netframework-4.7.2) and I recommend also [`System.Data`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
```